# setInterval function not working properly on scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to addClass 'current' for every 3 seconds once the user reaches the section. It's working properly outside the onScroll function but I have added inside onScroll function it's not working properly the class (current) adding randomly.

setInterval function not working properly inside OnScroll event. it's working outside of the function.

```js
function lightBoxNavAddClass() {
  var current = $('.light-box-nav li.current').removeClass('current'),
    next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.siblings().filter(':first');
  next.addClass('current');

};
// setInterval(function () {
//        lightBoxNavAddClass();
//        $('.light-box-nav li.current a').trigger('click');
//       }, 3000);


$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.hccb-lightbox').position().top) {
    console.log('I have been reached');
    setInterval(function() {
      lightBoxNavAddClass();
      // $('.light-box-nav li.current a').trigger('click');
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    return false
  }
})
```

```css
.light-box-nav li.current a {
  background-color: #E61D2B;
  color: #fff;
}

.light-box-nav li a {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 18%);
  padding: 11px 32px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #A3A3A3;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="hccb-lightbox position-relative">
  <div class="light-box-nav">
    <h5 class="heading-title-1 text-white mb-3 ">Audi</h5>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item font-bold current">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="factories">BMW</a>
      </li>

      <li class="list-inline-item font-bold ">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="warehouses">MG</a>
      </li>

      <li class="list-inline-item font-bold ">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="distributorsRetailers">Hyndai</a>
      </li>

      <li class="list-inline-item font-bold ">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="visicoolers">TATA</a>
      </li>

      <li class="list-inline-item font-bold ">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="fountains">Tesla</a>
      </li>



    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: try replacing **setInterval** with **setTimeout**

Comment: It's not working. I have observed setInterval function working very fastly inside onScroll function and if I add in the outside Onscroll function working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your on scroll callback function is executing on every scroll therefore every scroll past the boundaries of your if condition

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.hccb-lightbox').position().top) {..
```

the callback is executing and multiple new instances of setInterval are being run in which you are adding lightBoxNavAddClass() numerous times.

To call setInterval just once after the condition has been met, you could add a `$(document).off('scroll')` (or whatever jQuery uses to remove events) after the setInterval. This will set the 3 second interval once and no longer listen for the scrolling event whilst allowing the interval to continue executing every 3 seconds